# Alarm clock subclass of a clock

Tags: python, object-oriented, inheritance

I have these two classes and they should remain separate classes, but I have a feeling that this could be implemented more efficiently and with less duplicate code. After googling around I still didn't figure a better way, so perhaps someone here could point me out. Ideally I want to get tick() method from Clock and just add alarm to it and also get set_time() method with additional attributes for setting the alarm time.

```
class Clock:

def __init__(self, hours, minutes, seconds):
    self.set_time(hours, minutes, seconds)

def set_time(self, hours, minutes, seconds):
    if hours < 0:
        self.hours = 0
    elif hours > 23:
        self.hours = 23
    else:
        self.hours = hours

    if minutes < 0:
        self.minutes = 0
    elif minutes > 59:
        self.minutes = 59
    else:
        self.minutes = minutes

    if seconds < 0:
        self.seconds = 0
    elif seconds > 59:
        self.seconds = 59
    else:
        self.seconds = seconds

def tick(self):
    while True:
        print(str(self.hours).zfill(2), ":", str(self.minutes).zfill(2), ":", str(self.seconds).zfill(2), sep="")
        self.seconds += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        if self.seconds == 60:
            self.seconds = 0
            self.minutes += 1
            if self.minutes == 60:
                self.minutes = 0
                self.hours += 1
                if self.hours == 24:
                    self.hours = 0


class AlarmClock(Clock):

def __init__(self, hours, minutes, seconds, alarm_hr, alarm_min, alarm_sec):
    super().__init__(hours, minutes, seconds)
    self.set_alarm(alarm_hr, alarm_min, alarm_sec)

def set_alarm(self, alarm_hr, alarm_min, alarm_sec):
    if alarm_hr < 0:
        self.alarm_hr = 0
    elif alarm_hr > 23:
        self.alarm_hr = 23
    else:
        self.alarm_hr = alarm_hr

    if alarm_min < 0:
        self.alarm_min = 0
    elif alarm_min > 59:
        self.alarm_min = 59
    else:
        self.alarm_min = alarm_min

    if alarm_sec < 0:
        self.alarm_sec = 0
    elif alarm_sec > 59:
        self.alarm_sec = 59
    else:
        self.alarm_sec = alarm_sec

def alarm(self):
    while True:
        print(str(self.hours).zfill(2), ":", str(self.minutes).zfill(2), ":", str(self.seconds).zfill(2), sep="")
        self.seconds += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        if self.seconds == 60:
            self.seconds = 0
            self.minutes += 1
            if self.minutes == 60:
                self.minutes = 0
                self.hours += 1
                if self.hours == 24:
                    self.hours = 0
        if self.hours == self.alarm_hr and self.minutes == self.alarm_min and self.seconds == self.alarm_sec:
            print("ALARM ALARM ALARM ALARM ALARM!!!!")
            break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have refactored some of your code, please note that I am ignoring pre-existing libraries since I assume there's a particular reason (educational or otherwise) behind implementing `Clock`, `tick`, etc. this way on your own.

**class Clock:**

```
class Clock:
    def __init__(self, hours: int, minutes: int, seconds: int):
        self.hours = self.normalize_time_in_range(hours, 0, 23)
        self.minutes = self.normalize_time_in_range(minutes, 0, 59)
        self.seconds = self.normalize_time_in_range(seconds, 0, 59)

    @staticmethod
    def normalize_time_in_range(value: int, lower_bound: int, upper_bound: int) -> int:
        if value < lower_bound:
            return lower_bound
        elif value > upper_bound:
            return upper_bound
        else:
            return value

    def start_ticking(self):
        while True:
            self.tick()

    def tick(self):
        print(f"{str(self.hours).zfill(2)}:{str(self.minutes).zfill(2)}:{str(self.seconds).zfill(2)}")
        self.seconds += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        if self.seconds == 60:
            self.seconds = 0
            self.minutes += 1
            if self.minutes == 60:
                self.minutes = 0
                self.hours += 1
                if self.hours == 24:
                    self.hours = 0
```

1. **normalize_value_in_range:** Notice you have a lot of duplicated logic in `set_time` and `set_alarm`. Most of the logic can be extracted to this more generic implementation.
2. **start_ticking and tick:** In your case I found it useful to seperate the loop from the actual tick logic so you can change the loop conditions in subclasses while reusing `tick`. You will see why this is useful in `AlarmClock`.
3. **Type annotations:** As you can see in the method heads I added some type hints to the newly added methods. This is generally a good idea in regards to documenting your code for yourself and others.

**class AlarmClock:**

```
class AlarmClock(Clock):
    def __init__(self, hours, minutes, seconds, alarm_hr, alarm_min, alarm_sec):
        super().__init__(hours, minutes, seconds)

        self.alarm_hr = self.normalize_value_in_range(alarm_hr, 0, 23)
        self.alarm_min = self.normalize_value_in_range(alarm_min, 0, 59)
        self.alarm_sec = self.normalize_value_in_range(alarm_sec, 0, 59)

        self.ticking = False

    def start_ticking(self):
        self.ticking = True
        while self.ticking:
            self.tick()

    def tick(self):
        super().tick()
        if self.hours == self.alarm_hr and self.minutes == self.alarm_min and self.seconds == self.alarm_sec:
            print("ALARM ALARM ALARM ALARM ALARM!!!!")
            self.ticking = False
```

1. **normalize_value_in_range:** We can now reuse this method to set our alarm time as well.
2. **start_ticking and tick:** Since we seperated the loop from the actual tick we can use `Clock.tick()` in our AlarmClock without the need for duplicate code. Adding the attribute `self.ticking` to `AlarmClock` allows us to break out of the loop across methods. The reason we could not reuse `tick()` before was because it contained the infinite `while True` loop, thereby not allowing us to intercept when the alarm_time is reached.

**class Time:**
Lastly, I would suggest seperating time logic from clock logic. This makes the clocks more concise and allows you to extend the functionality of the `Time` class as needed. You could also say it allows the clocks to focus on their main functionality. Again, I am ignoring the existence of libraries for this task, since I presume you want to implement the entire logic on your own. Specialized libraries like `datetime` are worth looking into since they provide a lot of comfortable functionality. One implementation might be the following:

```
class Time:
    def __init__(self, hours: int, minutes: int, seconds: int):
        self.hours = self.normalize_value_in_range(hours, 0, 23)
        self.minutes = self.normalize_value_in_range(minutes, 0, 59)
        self.seconds = self.normalize_value_in_range(seconds, 0, 59)

    @staticmethod
    def normalize_value_in_range(value: int, lower_bound: int, upper_bound: int) -> int:
        if value < lower_bound:
            return lower_bound
        elif value > upper_bound:
            return upper_bound
        else:
            return value

    def increment(self):
        self.seconds += 1
        if self.seconds == 60:
            self.seconds = 0
            self.minutes += 1
            if self.minutes == 60:
                self.minutes = 0
                self.hours += 1
                if self.hours == 24:
                    self.hours = 0

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.hours == other.hours and self.minutes == other.minutes and self.seconds == other.seconds

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{str(self.hours).zfill(2)}:{str(self.minutes).zfill(2)}:{str(self.seconds).zfill(2)}"


class Clock:
    def __init__(self, hours: int, minutes: int, seconds: int):
        self.time = Time(hours, minutes, seconds)

    def start_ticking(self):
        while True:
            self.tick()

    def tick(self):
        print(self.time)
        self.time.increment()
        time.sleep(1)


class AlarmClock(Clock):
    def __init__(self, hours, minutes, seconds, alarm_hr, alarm_min, alarm_sec):
        super().__init__(hours, minutes, seconds)
        self.alarm_time = Time(alarm_hr, alarm_min, alarm_sec)

        self.ticking = False

    def start_ticking(self):
        self.ticking = True
        while self.ticking:
            self.tick()

    def tick(self):
        super().tick()
        if self.time == self.alarm_time:
            print("ALARM ALARM ALARM ALARM ALARM!!!!")
            self.ticking = False
```

Answer (score 2):

Your project provides a good illustration of a general principle in writing
software: internal data storage (for example, how a Clock class keeps track of
the time) and external presentation (for example, how a time should be printed
for a user) are two different things.

Your code can be greatly simplified by storing the data in the most basic
format possible: total seconds. Only when needed for the benefit of users do
you worry about assembling a time in `HH:MM:SS` format. If we take this
approach, you'll need a method to convert hours, minutes, seconds to total
seconds. And we also need a way to convert the other direction. For brevity,
I'm ignoring validation here:

```
import time

class Clock:

    def __init__(self, hours, minutes, seconds):
        # Just store total seconds.
        self.total_secs = self.hms_to_seconds(hours, minutes, seconds)

    def hms_to_seconds(self, hours, minutes, seconds):
        # Simple converter.
        return hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds

    # Properties to retrieve user-facing values when needed.

    @property
    def hours(self):
        return self.total_secs // 3600

    @property
    def minutes(self):
        return (self.total_secs - (3600 * self.hours)) // 60

    @property
    def seconds(self):
        return self.total_secs - 3600 * self.hours - 60 * self.minutes

    def tick(self):
        # Make tick do less, so you can re-use it.
        print(f'{self.hours:>02}:{self.minutes:>02}:{self.seconds:>02}')
        self.total_secs += 1
        time.sleep(1)

    def run(self):
        # A basic clock just ticks forever.
        while True:
            self.tick()

class AlarmClock(Clock):

    def __init__(self, hours, minutes, seconds, alarm_hr, alarm_min, alarm_sec):
        super().__init__(hours, minutes, seconds)
        self.alarm_secs = self.hms_to_seconds(alarm_hr, alarm_min, alarm_sec)

    def run(self):
        # An alarm clock ticks and alarms.
        while True:
            self.tick()
            if self.total_secs >= self.alarm_secs:
                print("ALARM ALARM ALARM ALARM ALARM!!!!")
                break

AlarmClock(1, 15, 0, 1, 15, 5).run()
```